# how to stop at an internal Maple proc?

Tags: maple

I want to see how Maple determined the type of an ODE. But can't set break point at internal Maple proc:

```
restart;
ode:=2*sqrt(a*diff(y(x),x))+x*diff(y(x),x)-y(x) = 0;
DEtools:-odeadvisor(ode);
      #[[_homogeneous, `class G`], _Clairaut]
```

But when I do

```
 stopat(DEtools:-odeadvisor);
```

it gives erorr

```
Error, invalid input: stopat expects its 1st argument, p, to be of type {`::`, name, string}, but received proc () option `Copyright (c) 1997 Waterloo Maple Inc. All rights reserved.`; `ODEtools/initialized` <> 'true' and `ODEtools/init`() <> 0; `ODEtools/odeadv`(args) end proc
```

Is it possible to set break point at `DEtools:-odeadvisor`?  showstat does not show much. I thought it was possible to view all Maple library code (other than the `builtin` ones).

But may be some are not possible to see in addition to the `builtin`? How does one know then which one can see and which one can't see? How one see the code the `DEtools:-odeadvisor`?

Maple 2018.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
restart;
ode:=2*sqrt(a*diff(y(x),x))+x*diff(y(x),x)-y(x) = 0:

showstat(DEtools[odeadvisor]);

stopat(`ODEtools/odeadv`);

DEtools:-odeadvisor(ode);
```